# Regex - All before an underscore, and all between second underscore and the last period?

Tags: regex

How do I get everything before the first underscore, and everything between the last underscore and the period in the file extension?

So far, I have everything before the first underscore, not sure what to do after that.

```
.+?(?=_)
```

**EXAMPLES:**

- 111111_SMITH, JIM_END TLD 6-01-20 THR LEWISHS.pdf
- 222222_JONES, MIKE_G URS TO 7.25 2-28-19 SA COOPSHS.pdf

**DESIRED RESULTS:**

- 111111_END TLD 6-01-20 THR LEWISHS
- 222222_G URS TO 7.25 2-28-19 SA COOPSHS

Comment: Your second example picks the "MIKE" before the last underscore...

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @AndyLester, Ultimately, I'm using PowerShell

Comment: Correct, I did not intend to capture MIKE, removing that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match the following regular expression that contains no capture groups.

```
^[^_]*|(?!.*_).*(?=\.)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZYKlVw/1)

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^        # match the beginning of the string
[^_]*    # match zero or more characters other than an underscore
|        # or
(?!      # begin negative lookahead
  .*_    # match zero or more characters followed by an underscore
)        # end negative lookahead
.*       # match zero or more characters greedily
(?=      # begin positive lookahead
  \.     # match a period
)        # end positive lookahead
```

---

`.*_` means to match zero or more characters *greedily*, followed by an underscore. To match greedily (the default) means to match as *many* characters as possible. Here that includes all underscores (if there are any) before the last one. Similarly, `.*` followed by `(?=\.)` means to match zero or more characters, possibly including periods, up to the last period.

Had I written `.*?_` (incorrectly) it would match zero or more characters *lazily*, followed by an underscore. That means it would match as *few* characters as possible before matching an underscore; that is, it would match zero or more characters up to, but not including, the *first* underscore.

---

If instead of capturing the two parts of the string of interest you wanted to remove the two parts of the string you don't want (as suggested by the desired results of your example), you could substitute matches of the following regular expression with empty strings.

```
_.*_|\.[^.]*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gqos1E/1)

This regular expression reads, "Match an underscore followed by zero of more characters followed by an underscore, or match a period followed by zero or more characters that are not periods, followed by the end of the string".

Comment: You're removing the trailing underscore in your second expression. Regarding the difference between a lazy quantifier `.*?` and a greedy one `.*`; when writing well performing expressions it's good to think of them in terms of how the regex engine applies them. Think of the latter as "jump to the end of the line" (which is what the engine effectively attempts) and the former as "stay as close to the beginning of the line as you can". The difference, assuming that the eventual match will be the same, is how many characters the engine has to add or give up in order to procure the match.

Comment: @oriberu, that was intentional. I interpreted the first sentence as meaning that neither the last underscored nor the period preceding the file name suffix were to be part of the second match. Unfortunately, the question is not clarified by the examples. The desired results show the second underscore as included in the matches but not the periods. Also, zb226 pointed out another problem with one example. As a result I concluded that my assumption was what was needed, but it is not it's an easy fix.

Comment: I agree that the question needs work. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, this answers the question!

Answer (score 3):

You could use 2 capture groups:

```
^([^_\n]+_).*\b([^\s_]*_.*)(?=\.)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([^_\n]+_)` Capture group 1, match any char except `_` or a newline followed by matching a `_`
- `.*\b` Match the rest of the line and match a word boundary
- `([^\s_]*_.*)` Capture group 2, optionally match any char except `_` or a whitespace char, then match `_` and the rest of the line
- `(?=\.)` Positive lookahead, assert a `.` to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJgtJF/1).

Another option could be using a non greedy version to get to the first `_` and make sure that there are no following underscores and then match the last dot:

```
^([^_\n]+_).*?(\S*_[^_\n]+)\.[^.\n]+$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KONyyO/1).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're very close. You could eliminate the names between the underscores by finding this
(_.+?_)
and replacing the returned value with a single underscore.

I am assuming that you did not intend your second result to include the name MIKE.

Comment: If you shift your capturing group a little and make an alternative for the file ending, you could extend your expression into something that meets the requirements as stated. Something like `_.+?(_)|\.\w+$` and replace by the captured group, which is not going to be set for the second alternative: `$1`.

Comment: Correct, I did not intend to capture 'Mike'  Editing the question to remove that part of the example.

Comment: Thank you for posting @coelfrith!  I like your thought process of removing between the underscores.  This would additionally need to remove the '.pdf'