# Regex, PowerShell, How can I get this to show up in PowerShell?

Tags: string, powershell

In using the following PowerShell Script with Regex.

**THE PROBLEM:** *I don't get any data returned for the Filename.*

**CURRENT RESULTS IN POWERSHELL:**

[image]

**EXPECTED RESULTS IN POWERSHELL:**

[image]

[This](https://regex101.com/r/vvWZNI/1) Regex Demo is doing what I would think it should be doing in Regex.  (Originating from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71270799/regex-all-before-an-underscore-and-all-between-second-underscore-and-the-last) question.)

**POWERSHELL SCRIPT:**

```
$InStuff = @('111111_SMITH, JIM_END TLD 6-01-20 THR LEWISHS.pdf','222222_JONES, MIKE_G URS TO 7.25 2-28-19 SA COOPSHS.pdf')


switch -Regex ($instuff) {
    '^(^.{0,6})*|(?!.*_).*(?=\.)'{     
        [pscustomobject]@{
            EmployeeID         = $matches.1
            FileName             = $matches.2            
        }
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:**
*What do I need to change to get the filename to show up in the PowerShell results?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple [`.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0) can achieve what you're looking for. The method will *split* the string into **3 tokens** which then get assigned to `$a` for the **EmployeeID**, `$null` for the **User** (we use `$null` here to simply ignore this token since you have already stated it was not of interest) and `$b` for the **FileName**. In PowerShell, this is known as [*multiple assignment*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.2#assigning-multiple-variables).

To remove the extension from the `$b` token, as requested in your comment, *regex* is also **not needed**, you can use [**Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=net-6.0) from `System.IO`.

```
$InStuff = @(
    '111111_SMITH, JIM_END TLD 6-01-20 THR LEWISHS.pdf'
    '222222_JONES, MIKE_G URS TO 7.25 2-28-19 SA COOPSHS.pdf'
)

foreach($i in $InStuff) {
    $a, $null, $b = $i.Split('_')
    [pscustomobject]@{
        EmployeeID = $a
        FileName   = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($b)
    }
}
```

Which results in:

```
EmployeeID FileName
---------- --------
111111     END TLD 6-01-20 THR LEWISHS
222222     G URS TO 7.25 2-28-19 SA COOPSHS
```

Comment: Thanks @Santiago Squarzon, I'm sorry, I originally I posted an incorrect link for the regex demo.  I updated it.  The regex excludes everything after the 6th character and the grabs between the last underscore and before the period.

Comment: Great job @SantiagoSquarzon!  I appreciate the help.  would you mind explaining what is happening with the split line you added?

Comment: How can I account to remove everything after the dot (part of the original regex in the post) and for any blanks in the Filename?

Comment: @JM1 do you want to ignore the line if the `$b` token is empty? I have added the explanation to my post. You haven't shown the actual data, and the array you have provided can be parsed using `.split()`

Comment: You make a valid point.  I will keep $b it's blank.  However, how can we use Split to also leave off the '.pdf'?   Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JM1 see my last update

Comment: @SandtiagoSquarzon, You are good at this and I am grateful for your help.